# Can't login after system update of Ubuntu 22.04.3 on 10/18/2023

Tags: updates, 22.04, login

I just installed system updates using Ubuntu Software Updater (or whatever the auto-update app is called). I can't log in after rebooting the PC. I tried:

- visible password to eliminate caps lock or similar problem
- logging in from the terminal

Were there any issues with the last update? What else can I do to log in?

---

I booted to GNU GRUB menu and selected the previous kernel version `6.2.0-33-generic` and my login worked just fine. I repeated the process, selecting the newest `6.2.0-34-generic` kernel and the login worked this time. No idea what was happening here.